# Get timestamp from firebase server

Tags: android, firebase

Can I get timestamp from firebase server?

I tried this method

```
Timestamp.now().getSeconds()
```

This method get timestamp from client so when the client change the date and time from settings the result of the method above will change also.

Comment: Real-time database or firestore?

Comment: @Shivam Firestore

Comment: use   val hashMap = HashMap<String?, Any?>()                                 hashMap["timestamp"] = FieldValue.serverTimestamp()